# When does APC allocate memory?

Tags: php, memory, alternative-php-cache

If I set `apc.shm_size = 64M`, will 64M of memory be allocated by APC when it starts or does it get allocated in chunks as it is needed?

Answer (score 1):

It is allocated at startup.
apc.shm_size = 64M is very low you should use much more (GB)if your server is running several websites. Use apc.php to check your config.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-size:
apc.shm_size defines the segment size.
The number of segments allocated is defined by the apc.shm_segments configuration value.